# Preview value of method return statement within expression?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am wondering if there is any way to see value used in an expression if it involved a function call while debugging in Visual Studio 2015?

To provide an example:

```
Object object;
object.setInteger(10);

int myInt = 20;

if (object.getInteger() + 5 >= myInt)
    //...
```

Here I can see that myInt = 20 by hovering over it during debug in VS2015, can I somehow easily see that `object.getInteger() + 5` == 15 without creating another int variable explicitly? Eg:

```
 int myNewInt = object.getInteger() + 5;

 if (myNewInt >= myInt)
     //...
```

Kind regards

Comment: A lot of the time if you are on auto it will show you `function so and so returned blah`.  You could also try hovering over the function with your mouse pointer.

Comment: You can just add it to the watch list. You can refresh the value at any time by clicking the button that will appear next to it when it might be out of date. Edit : Beware that if the function has side effects, this solution may alter the behavior of your program.

Comment: @NathanOliver That doesn't work for me unfortunately. Should it?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you, I'll look in to the watch list, it's not a tool I am currently familiar with.

Comment: IIRC it's been something they have been improving.  I think 2017 does a pretty good job, 2015 less so and the older version even less so.

Comment: @notanalien this is visible just after leaving the sub-function with Shift-F11